Solving the non-linear recurrence $d_i + 2 i d_{i-1} = e_{i+1}$ (via generating functions)
I've been studying the recurrence $$d_i + 2i d_{i-1} = e_{i+1} =: (-2a)^{i+1}e^{-a^2} \quad\quad\quad a \in \mathbb{R}$$
attempting to solve for the sequence $(d_i)$. (The $d_0$ case is defined equivalently, where $d_i = 0$ for all $i<0$).
Via generating functions, if I define
$$\begin{aligned} 
D(x)&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty d_ix^i \\ E(x) &= \sum_{i=0}^\infty e_{i+1}x^i = \frac{-2ae^{-a^2}}{1+2ax}
\end{aligned}$$
then the recurrence relation becomes the differential equation $$\begin{aligned} 
D + 2x(xD)' &= E \\
D' + D \cdot \frac{1+2x}{2x^2} &= \frac{-ae^{-a^2}}{(1+2ax)x^2} \\
(D \cdot x e^{-1 / 2x})' &= \frac{-ae^{-a^2}e^{-1/2x}}{(1+2ax)x}
\end{aligned}$$
and solving this gives $$D = ae^{a(1-a)} \text{Ei}(-a - \frac{1}{2x})x^{-1}e^{1/2x} \color{gray}{ + c x^{-1} e^{1/2x}}$$which involves the exponential integral, $\text{Ei}$.
The issue I'm finding here is I cannot find a series expansion of the form $D=\sum d_i x^i$ - nor do I know if one even exists. The grey term contains $e^{1/2x}$ which is not analytic, so choosing $c=0$ gets rid of that - but the first term still remains.
Another problem is that, if $a=0$, we have $d_i+2id_{i-1}=0$, (since $e_0 = 1$ and $e_i = 0$ for all $i \neq 0$). My solution in this case would be the grey term above - giving $d_i = 0 \ \ 
 \forall i$. However Wolfram gives the solution $d_i=c(-2)^ii!$, from which I note that the series $\sum{c(-2)^ii!x^i}$ has zero radius of convergence. I suspect this to be the issue - the generating function method I used glosses over some convergence issues and gives a nonsensical solution, while the actual solution can’t be found this way.
My question is if there is a way to solve this with generating functions; and if not, is it possible to know when this isn’t possible a priori; what method could I use derive the Wolfram solution for $a=0$; and if it is possible, maybe a solution to the general case, where $a \neq 0$. Thanks in advance!

Because of the factor of $i$ on the left, I think it's going to work out better with exponential generating functions.

There are some mistakes in your generating function approach because of initial conditions; the stated recurrence holds for $i\ge1$ but your first differential equation is as if you summed from $i=0$. But, there is evidence to suggest an ordinary generating function approach wouldn’t work. Possible and very popular alternatives to combat the fast factorial growth rate include the use of exponential generating functions.
More simply we can use “discrete integration” though. As you can integrate ODEs of form $y’+f(x)y=g(x)$, you can discretely integrate the series analogue. It’s just summation, but the language of integration is helpful. Idea: $(d_2+4d_1)-4(d_1+2d_0)+8d_0=d_2$ recovers the value of $d_2$ and every bracketed term on the LHS is known. This feels like taking incremental (telescoping) steps, and for me it feels like integration. I think there’s a whole thing about this, the Newton or Newton-Euler calculus of differences. Anyway: $$d_n=(-2)^n n!d_0+n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-2)^{n-k}}{k!}(d_k+2kd_{k-1})$$Generalising the above. This becomes, using the recurrence: $$(-2)^n n!d_0+(-2)^{n+1}e^{-a^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{k!}a^{k+1}$$
I’m not confident in a meaningful closed form for that; you can use exponential polynomial notation though. But, you can at least see the radius of convergence for the exponential generating function from this.

Thank you! As predicted, the exponential generating function gave a more well behaved series, yet extracting the coefficients seems quite nasty(I believe the series is of the form $e^{-2ax}/(1+2x)$). However the ‘discrete integration’ method seems to work! Thanks again, Nathan.

@HabeebM beeb ${}{}$
